# Proof of 9.30c Axler's Linear Algebra Done right

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, adjoint-operators

I have the following question of the proof of 9.30(c) in 'Linear Algebra Done Right' by Sheldon Axler.

Theorem 9.30 states the following: 'Suppose V is an inner product space, $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$ is normal, and U is a subspace of V that is invariant under T. Then

(a) $U^\perp$ is invariant under T

(b) U is invariant under $T^*$

(c) $(T|_{U})^* = (T^*)|_U$

(d) I'll skip it.

When proving (a) he gets to the following matrix of T (image below). $e_1,...,e_m$ is an orthonormal basis of U, and $e_1,...,e_m,f_1,...,f_n$ is an orthonormal basis of V. A is a mxm matrix and C is an nxn matrix.

His proof of (c) is pretty straightforward, but i was wondering if one could proof (c) by saying that  $M(T|_{U})^* = M(T^*)|_U$ implies  $(T|_{U})^* = (T^*)|_U$?

I'll appreciate any guidence.

[image]

Comment: I can't resist but say that choosing bases and so on introduces a large load of irrelevant detail that does not actually help the proof. Is this truly what happens in that book?!?

Comment: I believe the way Axler develops his books makes it relevant for proving (a). The reason i mentioned the basis is to give some context.